# ¿Mejor manera de devolver un valor de un método?

Tags: javascript

He visto varios ejemplos en los que devuelve directamente el resultado y en otros retornan de esta manera this.nueva_variable. En el ejemplo de abajo la variable bmi no se ha creado en el objeto.

```javascript
      calcBMI: function () {
        return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
      },
```

o

```javascript
      calcBMI: function () {
        this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
        return this.bmi;
      },
```

Comment: Estás en Stack Overflow en Español, por favor, traduce tu pregunta

Comment: La pregunta está escrita en un idioma diferente al idioma oficial de este sitio, que es el español.

Comment: Las dos maneras de devolver el valor funcionan aparentemente igual **en términos de devolución** pero el segundo (usando this.atributo) asigna el valor a un miembro del objeto en uso y lo deja "disponible" dentro del mismo para usos futuros.

Answer (score 6):

Revisé el caso, les comparto mis notas.

**Memory Allocation** registra variables durante el levantamiento, **pero no propiedades**. Ahora, propiedades como `this.bmi`, la cual no forma parte de las propiedades del objeto `_Objeto`, se registran en memoria con valor tipo `undefined`:

```js
let _Objeto = {
  mass:30,
  height:2,
  keepTrackOf: function(){
    console.log("keepTrackOf this.bmi: ", this.bmi);
    
  },
  calcBMI01: function () {
    return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
  },
  calcBMI02: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  }
}

let instance = {..._Objeto};
instance.keepTrackOf();
```

Por otro lado, si se solicitan las propiedades del Objeto, `this.bmi` no se devuelve:

```js
let _Objeto = {
  mass:30,
  height:2,
  keepTrackOf: function(){
    console.log("keepTrackOf this.bmi: ", this.bmi);
    
  },
  calcBMI01: function () {
    return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
  },
  calcBMI02: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  }
}

let instance = {..._Objeto};
instance.keepTrackOf();
console.log("Propiedades de instance: ", Object.keys(instance));
```

Una vez ejecutádo el método que usa a `this.bmi`, la misma ya se devuelve como otra propiedad más del `Objeto`:

```js
let _Objeto = {
  mass:30,
  height:2,
  keepTrackOf: function(){
    console.log("keepTrackOf this.bmi: ", this.bmi);
    
  },
  calcBMI01: function () {
    return this.mass / this.height ** 2;
  },
  calcBMI02: function () {
    this.bmi = this.mass / this.height ** 2;
    return this.bmi;
  }
}

let instance = {..._Objeto};
console.log("Propiedades de Objeto: ", Object.keys(instance));
instance.keepTrackOf();
console.log("calcBMI02: ",instance.calcBMI02());
console.log("despues de usar calcBMI02: ", Object.keys(instance));
instance.keepTrackOf();
```

Después de observar este comportamiento, considero que si se va a usar esta propiedad `this.bmi` de forma regular por el programa, lo más correcto sería incluirla en las propiedades del objeto **explícitamente**, para evitar confusiones sobre lo que hace y cómo se usa. Así lograremos que nuestro código sea más inteligible.

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.